# XmlJavaTypeAdapter not being detected

Tags: java, jaxb

Hopefully an easy one for JAXB experts:

I am trying to marshal an immutable class that does *not* define a default no-arg constructor.  I have defined an `XmlAdapter` implementation but it doesn't seem to be picked up.  I have put together a simple self-contained example, which is still failing to work.  Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong?

**Immutable Class**

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(FooAdapter.class)
@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {
  private final String name;
  private final int age;

  public Foo(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getName() { return name; }
  public int getAge() { return age; }
}
```

**Adapter and Value Type**

```
public class FooAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AdaptedFoo, Foo> {
  public Foo unmarshal(AdaptedFoo af) throws Exception {
    return new Foo(af.getName(), af.getAge());
  }

  public AdaptedFoo marshal(Foo foo) throws Exception {
    return new AdaptedFoo(foo);
  }
}

class AdaptedFoo {
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public AdaptedFoo() {}

  public AdaptedFoo(Foo foo) {
    this.name = foo.getName();
    this.age = foo.getAge();
  }

  @XmlAttribute
  public String getName() { return name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

  @XmlAttribute
  public int getAge() { return age; }
  public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
}
```

**Marshaller**

```
public class Marshal {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = new Foo("Adam", 34);

    try {
      JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
      Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

      // output pretty printed
      jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

      jaxbMarshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);              
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }   
  }
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Foo does not have a no-arg default constructor.
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at Foo

        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:451)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:283)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:126)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1142)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:130)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:235)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:445)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
        at Marshal2.main(Marshal2.java:11)
```

Note that I am using JDK 1.7.0_05.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following should help:

**FOO AS ROOT OBJECT**

When `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` is specified at the type level it only applies to fields/properties referencing that class, and not when an instance of that class is a root object in your XML tree.  This means that you will have to convert `Foo` to `AdaptedFoo` yourself, and create the `JAXBContext` on `AdaptedFoo` and not `Foo`.

**Marshal**

```
package forum11966714;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Marshal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Foo foo = new Foo("Adam", 34);

      try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AdaptedFoo.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        // output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(new AdaptedFoo(foo), System.out);              
      } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }   
    }
  }
```

**AdaptedFoo**

You will need to add an `@XmlRootElement` annotation to the `AdaptedFoo` class.  You can remove the same annotation from the `Foo` class.

```
package forum11966714;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
class AdaptedFoo {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public AdaptedFoo() {
    }

    public AdaptedFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.name = foo.getName();
        this.age = foo.getAge();
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

---

**FOO AS NESTED OBJECT**

When `Foo` isn't the root object everything works the way you have it mapped.  I have extended your model to demonstrate how this would work.

**Bar**

```
package forum11966714;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Bar {

    private Foo foo;

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

Note that the JAXB reference implementation will not let you specify the `Foo` class when bootstrapping the `JAXBContext`.

```
package forum11966714;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bar.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            File xml = new File("src/forum11966714/input.xml");
            Bar bar = (Bar) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(bar, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bar>
    <foo name="Jane Doe" age="35"/>
</bar>
```

Comment: Thanks Blaise! (I think it was your blog I was originally looking at).  Looks like the problem was me specifying Foo.class to the JAXBContext during the bootstrapping.  Shame JAXB doesn't work out at this point that I've specified an adapter for Foo ... makes the bootstrapping a bit fiddly.

Comment: @bdoughan You seem to be an expert in this hard question about marshaling/unmarshaling) Maybe you can guide me a bit in my question. I have an XML that has `<ROOT>` as a root element and a lot of one type elements inside it, e.g. `<ROOT><elem1 attr="value"</elem1><<elem2 attr="value"</elem2><elem3 attr="value"</elem3></ROOT>` etc. And what I'm trying to do is to map this on a `Map<String, MyType> root` object to let those elements be dynamic. But I didn't succeed so far. I wrote a `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` but it doesn't pick as in the source question.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not the case, but if you have such an error when you put @XmlJavaTypeAdapter for the field - check that you specified the namespace. You may need it.

In my case this didn't work:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Expiration")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
private Date expiration;
```

until a namespace has been specified:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Expiration", namespace="http://site/your.namespace")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
private Date expiration;
```