# Getting XmlJavaTypeAdapter and interfaces to play nicely

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a parent-child relationship whereby the child class: `Foo` is immutable and does not define a default no-arg constructor.  The parent class: `Bar` references the child through an interface: `IFoo`.  I have defined an adapter to solve the constructor issue but am now hitting another problem whereby JAXB is complaining that the class Foo is not known to this context.

If I attempt to solve this by bootstrapping my `JAXBContext` with `Foo.class` then I receive the lack of default constructor error instead.

Note that I am trying to follow the interface mapping approach described in [3.2.1 of the Unofficial JAXB Guide](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html).

Do I need to take a different interface mapping approach to solve this problem? I suspect that marking each interface implementation using `XmlRootElement` means my adapter code isn't being run (as described by Blaise Doughan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966714/xmljavatypeadapter-not-being-detected/11967459#11967459)).  This makes me wonder whether these two approaches are inherently incompatible and that I need to use one of the other interface mapping techniques described.

```
public interface IFoo {
  String getName();
  int getAge();
}

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(FooAdapter.class)
@XmlRootElement
public class Foo implements IFoo {
  private final String name;
  private final int age;

  public Foo(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getName() { return name; }
  public int getAge() { return age; }
}

public class FooAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AdaptedFoo, Foo> {
  @Override
  public Foo unmarshal(AdaptedFoo af) throws Exception {
    return new Foo(af.getName(), af.getAge());
  }

  @Override
  public AdaptedFoo marshal(Foo foo) throws Exception {
    AdaptedFoo ret = new AdaptedFoo();
    ret.setName(foo.getName());
    ret.setAge(foo.getAge());
    return ret;
  }
}

public class AdaptedFoo {
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public AdaptedFoo() {}

  @XmlAttribute
  public String getName() { return name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

  @XmlAttribute
  public int getAge() { return age; }
  public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Bar {
  @XmlAnyElement
  private IFoo foo;
  private int baz;

  public Bar() {}

  public IFoo getFoo() { return foo; }
  public void setFoo(IFoo foo) { this.foo = foo; }

  public int getBaz() { return baz; }
  public void setBaz(int baz) { this.baz = baz; }
}

public class Marshal {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = new Foo("Adam", 34);
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.setFoo(foo);
    bar.setBaz(10);

    try {
      JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bar.class, AdaptedFoo.class);
      Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

      // output pretty printed
      jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

      jaxbMarshaller.marshal(bar, System.out);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
$ java Marshal
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class Foo nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class Foo nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:311)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
        at Marshal.main(Marshal.java:20)
Caused by: com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class Foo nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class Foo nor any of its super class is known to this context.
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:235)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:250)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleReferenceNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleReferenceNodePr
operty.java:102)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:341)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:582)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:323)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:483)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class Foo nor any of its super class is known to this context.
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:573)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleReferenceNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleReferenceNodePr
operty.java:94)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use and `@XmlElement` annotation on the `foo` property and specify the implementation type, then your use case should work.

```
  @XmlElement(type=Foo.class)
  private IFoo foo;
```

**Bar**

Below is an updated version of your `Bar` class

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Bar {
  @XmlElement(type=Foo.class)
  private IFoo foo;
  private int baz;

  public Bar() {}

  public IFoo getFoo() { return foo; }
  public void setFoo(IFoo foo) { this.foo = foo; }

  public int getBaz() { return baz; }
  public void setBaz(int baz) { this.baz = baz; }
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-interface-fronted-models.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but looks like I accepted it too soon.  I get the same error (relating to Foo not having a no-arg ctor) - It's as if the XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation is being ignored.