# Jaxb additional wrapper arround Base Class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a Sub Class **Child** which derives from the Base Class **Parent**. I want to add a Wrapper around the attributes of the Base Class.

**Parent.java**

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Parent {

    int a;
    int b;

    String name;

    public Parent() {
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Child.java**

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Child extends Parent {

    private String foo;

    public Child() {

    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

**output.xml**

```
<child>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>3</b>
    <name>name</name>
    <foo>foo</foo>
</child>
```

But i want something like this:

```
<child>
    <foo>foo</foo>
    <parent>
        <a>1</a>
        <b>3</b>
        <name>name</name>
    </parent>
</child>
```

I hope somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

What you'd like to do is doable, but probably not worth the trouble. You will need to implement an [XmlAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) for your `Child` class,

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public final class ChildAdapter extends
XmlAdapter<PrintedType, Child> {

    @Override
    public Child unmarshal(PrintedType v) throws Exception {
        Child ret = new Child();
        ret.setFoo(v.foo);
        ret.setA(v.parent.getA());
        ret.setB(v.parent.getB());
        ret.setName(v.parent.getName());
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public PrintedType marshal(Child v) throws Exception {
        PrintedType ret = new PrintedType();
        ret.parent = v;
        ret.foo = v.getFoo();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

as well as a value type that generates the XML representation you would like:

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="child")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PrintedType {
    String foo;
    Parent parent;
}
```

Then, if you would like to marshal an instance of `Child` as the root element (as opposed to having a `Child` member field in some other class, and marshaling that class), you actually have to convert `Child` to the `PrintedType` first (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11967459/4854749). So a sample test class might be

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setA(1);
        child.setB(3);
        child.setName("name");
        child.setFoo("foo");

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(PrintedType.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        PrintedType ret = new PrintedType();
        ret.parent = child;
        ret.foo = child.getFoo();

        marshaller.marshal(ret, System.out);
    }
}
```

Are you sure this makes sense for the problem you are trying to solve? I do not know your context, but ask yourself which of these sounds more appropriate: `Child` **is a** `Parent`, or `Child` **contains** `Parent`? If it's the latter, you can make things a whole lot simpler by doing away with inheritance and using composition (making `Child` **contain** a `Parent` field). Then you wouldn't need adapter classes, and `Child` would marshal exactly in the way you'd like.

Comment: Proposing the "contains" refacturing for Child is absolutely adequate. If the required XML structure makes any sense, then Child is composed from the Parent stuff and the foo attribute. +1 (Note to @Clemens: Use  delegation in Child for easy access to its Parent's component.)